# Ajax not returning success result in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to get a return value from a when the database is updated. I used AJAX to send the data to a function inside functions.php by one of the Wordpress plugins' folder. I tried to alert on both success and fail function, and it has always invoked the fail function. How do I know if the AJAX response is successful so that i could do some additional code when it is successful.

SCRIPT

```
     function removeUser( department , user ){
            var value = { user_id: user , dep_name: department.id };
            $('#'+department.id+ user +"_div").hide();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: value
            });
        }
```

functions.php

```
function removeUser(){
    if(isset($_POST['user_id'])){
        //echo $_POST['user_id'];
        //echo $_POST['dep_name'];

        $user_meta = get_user_meta($_POST['user_id'], 'wpwf_quotation_position');
        $user_department = json_decode ($user_meta[0]);
        //print_r ($user_department);
        //echo (json_encode($user_department));

        foreach ($user_department as $key => $value){

            if ($value == strtolower($_POST['dep_name'])){

                //print_r ($user_department);
                unset($user_department[$key]);
                $user_department = array_values($user_department);
                //print_r ($user_department);
                //echo (json_encode($user_department));
                //print_r (json_encode($user_department));
                update_user_meta( $_POST['user_id'], 'wpwf_quotation_position', json_encode($user_department));
                break;
            }
            //echo $key." : ". $value ." - " . strtolower($_POST['dep_name'])."<br>";
        }
        //echo 'ssss';
        wp_send_json($_POST);
    }

 }
 add_action('init', 'removeUser');
```

The above code run well, but what I actually want to do is as below, but the success function is not called. What am i missing here or have done wrongly?

```
    function removeUser( department , user ){
            var value = { user_id: user , dep_name: department.id };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: value,
                success:function() {
                    $('#'+department.id+ user +"_div").hide();
                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: Do you have a 500 or a 200 response ? do you try to simply set an alert in the success ?

Comment: I don't have a 500 / 200 responses. I just want to do something when it is success. I tried fail function, it actually invoked it.

Comment: @ant I have checked on the response like you have mentioned, it stated 200 OK

Answer (score 0):

You should be using your browser console to debug this kind of thing. At the moment i'd say you are getting 'undefined is not a function" error meaning it dosen't recognise $, use safemode jQuery instead (jQuery.ajax).

Also you were missing the url and action from your ajax call.

```
function removeUser( department , user ){
        var value = { action: 'removeUser'/*assuming this is your ajax action */, user_id: user , dep_name: department.id };

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
            data: value,
            success:function(output) {
                console.log(output); // have a look at the console to find your values prob something like output.user_id
                jQuery('#'+department.id+ user +"_div").hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Also i cant see that you have hooked the php function to wp_ajax also. I'm assuming you have done this?